# issue while constructing NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am making `NSDate` from this string but Every time I am getting `Previous Month` from `Selected Month`

I am not able to find the bug:

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

  [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM/yyyy"];

  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];

  NSLog(@"------Date----%@",date);
```

I have tried with many `Datestrings` some are with Logs are:

```
  strDate =---- 01/Jan/2016
  ------Date----2015-12-31 18:30:00 +0000

  strDate =----01/Dec/2015
  ------Date----2015-11-30 18:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: what is the timezone of your device. let me guess: india

Comment: yes  @vikingosegundo you are right..But I have used Default time zone. is it not enough?

Comment: when you create a date, your default time zone is taken into account. when you print a date directly, UTC timezone is used -> the difference is 5:30.

Comment: So How can I resolve this ?

Comment: there is nothing to resolve. just use a nsdateformatter to print it. and next time search for it: this kind of question are answered zillions of times.

Comment: @vikingosegundo  thnks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As viking says, what you are seeing is an artifact of the way you are displaying your resulting date. When you log an NSDate object in NSLog, it is always displayed in UTC. If your date does not have a time component, midnight is assumed. If your time zone is AFTER UTC, midnight in your time zone will be displayed as the previous day.

I suggest you create a display date formatter to display your resulting dates, and use that:

```
- (NSString *) displayStringForDate: (NSDate *) date
{
   static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
   if (dateFormatter == nil)
   {
     //This date formatter will default to the current time zone, like you want.
     dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
     //Adjust the date format as desired
   {
   return [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];
}
```

Then use that method in your test code:

```
NSLog(@"------Date----%@", [self displayStringForDate: date]);
```

Comment: I would code it as a category method on NSDate

Comment: Agreed, that would be a good way to do it.